# Parse componentDidMount values in render with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new using react. I'd like to get content from firebase and parse it in render. So I try:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        data: null
    }
}


componentDidMount() {
    var feedRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').limitToLast(10);
    feedRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

        this.setState({ data: snapshot.val(), loading: false }); // error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of null

    });
}

render() {

    return this.state.loading ? (
        <div>
            <Spinner />
        </div>
    ) : (

        <>
                <div>
                    // how to put firebase content here?
                </div>
        </>

    );
}
```

I'd like to get content from firebase (user name, img) and place it in render. How can I make it?

Comment: have you tried using an arrow function for the `feedRef.once` callback? i.e `feedRef.once('value', async (snapshot) => { this.setState... })`
If that fixes it i'll put it in an answer (not 100% sure that'll fix it, hence the comment). Arrow functions don't redefine `this` - instead they use the enclosing scope.

Comment: @TomOakley yeah, it was the problem! I should use arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map function to iterate over data state and render the list of items inside data state.

Please to sure to use `${item.WHATEVER_YOUR_FIELD_IS}` inside map function.

```
<div>
   {this.state.data.map(item => {

     return(
      <div>
         <h1>${item.username}</h1>
         <img src=`${item.imgURL}`/>
      </div>
   )
})}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! and do you know why I get error when try to set the state? error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Comment: data should be initailze with [ ] (empty array) not with null

Comment: I change it to [] but now I have: TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Answer (score 2):

You pass a regular function to `feedRef.once` and it gets it's own `this`.
You should use an arrow function:

```
feedRef.once('value', async (snapshot) => {
```

or save `this` in other variable:

```
const me = this;
feedRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

    me.setState({ data: snapshot.val(), loading: false }); // error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of null

});
```

Comment: ah I should have been more confident in my assumption! I commented this but wasn't sure. Given you an upvote

Comment: Thanks for your answer! and the part to parse the data? could you help completing the answer with it? thanks again!

Comment: It depends on the `snapshot.val()` shape. You can use `{JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}` to output a json dump of your data. It seems that you should get an array of posts. But it might be somewhere deep inside `snapshot.val()`

Comment: @UjinT34 firebase returns an object.